# Создание класса для XML-структуры

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, jackson

Мне необходимо взаимодействовать с REST сервисом, который отдает ответы в XML. Структура XML-документа такая:

```
<RestcommResponse>
    <Clients>
        <Client>
        ...
        </Client>
        <Client>
        ...
        </Client>
    </Clients>
</RestcommResponse>
```

Я использую Spring с его RestTemplate-классом. Маппинг при помощи jackson-dataformat-xml. Я бы хотел написать класс Client, на свойства которого при помощи аннотаций будут маппиться элементы узла Client, и в ответе RestTemplate я получу List. Но мне мешают два верхних элемента документа: RestcommResponse и Clients. Как можно их обойти?

Comment: получить ноду\XmlElement?

Comment: Заюзать jaxb и обернуть данные клиентов в коллекцию?

Comment: @GenCloud сейчас на это и перешел, но вообще странно, я не нашел возможности конфигурирования такого простого дела аннотациями (как в случае с json)

Comment: Эм, jaxb  и есть стандартное апи конфигурирования "этого дела" посредством аннотаций